# centos 5.5 + tomcat 6.0 + sun jvm = ???? instead of russian characters

Tags: centos, tomcat

I installed in user's home directory jdk 1.6, tomcat 6.
When i deploy my app to server (no matter war or exploded) all my russian letters (`response.getWriter().write("SOME_RUSSIAN_TEXT_HERE")`) becomes '?': `??????`
All works fine under WinXP32+tomcat 6 installed in development machine.

Files charset is UTF8.

`locale` command:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

tomcat connector settings:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your generated html page has correct headers like ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru" >
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="ru" />
```

If it does not supply them - your web server can supply charset for the whole site.

You can check this via command  lynx -head -dump http://my.websyte.com